# Matrices proofs

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

Let $A,B$ be a $n × n$ matrices

$A = I + AB$

Prove:

1) A is invertible and AB = BA.

2) If B is a symmetric matrix then so is A.

3) $B^3 = 0$ if and only if $A = I + B + B^2$

OK for the first one I did:

$$ A-AB=I $$

$$ A(I-B) = I $$ That's why A is invertible

Then $ I - B = A^{-1} $  so,

$$ AA^{-1} = I $$ and also $$ A^{-1}A = I $$ so

$ A(I-B)=I $ and also $ (I-B)A=I $ so

$ AB = A-I $ and also $ BA=A-I $ so therefore

$$ AB = BA $$

For 2 I said that if $ B = I - A^{-1} $ and $B$ is symmetric so $  B^t = B $

$ B^t = I^t - (A^{-1})^t $

$ I - (A^{-1})^t =  I - A^{-1} $

$ (A^{-1})^t =  A^{-1} $

$ A^t = A $

that's why A is also symmetric.

Any idea for 3? I couldn't succeed in both sides.
Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Hint** $$
B^3 = 0 \iff I - B^3 = I
$$and now use $$
I - B^3 = (I-B)(I + B+ B^2)
$$